# args with filter() in Django

Tags: python, django

I begin to learn Django with the official tutorial
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/#ideas-for-more-tests

In order to do the following :

> it’s silly that Questions can be published on the site that have no
>   Choices. So, our views could check for this, and exclude such
>   Questions. Our tests would create a Question without Choices and then
>   test that it’s not published, as well as create a similar Question
>   with Choices, and test that it is published.

I added `, choice_set__count__gt=0` to `filter()` - just want to ensure the number of the choices corresponding to each question is bigger than 0, then throw out the exception

```
FieldError at /polls/
Cannot resolve keyword 'choice_set' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question_text
```

full code

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), choice_set__count__gt=0
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

(1) I wonder why the exception happened here? any way to correct it?

(2) According to the exception, it seems that each question object has a choice filed, where does this field come from ?

(3) Any better solution to solve the root problem ? I think amending the Question class is a good way to solve the actual problem.

models from [here](https://bpaste.net/show/56d83049dd33)

Comment: Can you update the post with models ?

Comment: @AbhinavI models from https://bpaste.net/show/56d83049dd33

Answer (score 1):

You can use `annotate` for this sort of thing - that will add an extra aggregate column and filter on that:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """Return the last five published questions."""
    return Question.objects \
        .annotate(choices=Count('choice')) \
        .filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), choices__gt=0) \
        .order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Now the resulting Question objects will also have a `choices` attribute set to the number of choices, which you can use later on.